# why firefox adds css styles unexpectedly?

Tags: css, firefox

The css is exactly like this:

```
body {
    background:#FFFFFF none repeat scroll 0;
    margin:2px 5px;
    font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:10pt;
}
```

But from firebug I see the style is:

```
body {
-moz-background-clip:border;
-moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
-moz-background-origin:padding;
background:#FFFFFF none repeat scroll 0 50%;
font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
font-size:10pt;
margin:2px 5px;
}
```

Why does firefox add those un-needed styles? How can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 2):

It is added by the rendering engine for its own use, so you cannot get rid of them.
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257118/why-does-firebug-add-moz-styles-when-inspecting-element-css) for details.

Comment: You cant get rid of them, but you dont need to display them.

Answer (score 0):

It is not adding anything for me. Are you sure these are not default styles saved in your default user stylesheet?

Comment: I suppose that you have Firefox 3.0. The extra -moz-background styles appeared in Firefox 3.5.